# What is this error: Because * depends on *

Tags: flutter

When I run "pub get" I get this error, how can I solve it:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in myApp...                        
Because myApp depends on audioplayers ^0.17.4 which depends on path_provider ^1.6.22, path_provider ^1.6.22 is required.

So, because myApp depends on path_provider ^2.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because myApp depends on path_provider ^2.0.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

I faced this error after I upraded to Flutter 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because `audioplayers` depends on a version of `path_provider` which is different from the version you are using in your app's dependency of `path_provider`.

Try using `any` in your `pubspec.yaml` when declaring your dependecies to `path_provider` and `audiplayers`.